# Log Backup occasionally blocked by automated update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, backup, transaction-log, cursors

We have a canary table in each of our databases that our automation updates once a minute.  The automation is a sql server agent job that utilizes a cursor to iterate over the databases and then executes dynamic sql to update the record.

We take log backups once every fifteen minutes using Ola's backups.

Every once in a while these two processes end up "blocking" each other.  The update just sits and spins and the log backup just sits and spins.  We can clear this by killing the spid associated with the update and then the log usually completes fairly quickly afterwards.

We aren't seeing any patterns to these, it just occurs once in a while.  We would like to prevent these so that both processes can keep running without causing issues, but I'm not seeing what the root cause really is.  We use SQL Sentry as a monitoring tool and it doesn't show any blocking in the databases for any timeframes that we have this issue.

**Code snippet for the update:**

```
DECLARE SQLCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY OPTIMISTIC
        FOR
        SELECT [name]
        FROM #Database
        WHERE IsReadOnly = 0
        AND IsSubscriber = 0
        AND SecondaryAG = 0
        AND Maintain = 1
        AND IsTFS = 0;

    OPEN SQLCursor;

    FETCH NEXT
        FROM SQLCursor
        INTO @DatabaseName;

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = CONCAT(N'USE [', @DatabaseName, ']
        

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo'' AND  TABLE_NAME = ''canary'')
        BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[canary](
                [CanaryID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
                [LastUpdated] [DATETIME] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_canary_LastUpdated] DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
                CONSTRAINT [PK_canary] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [CanaryID] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
            PRINT ''', @DatabaseName, ' created table.''
        END;

        DECLARE @Count INT;

        SELECT @Count = COUNT(1)
        FROM dbo.canary;

        IF @Count = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.canary SET LastUpdated = GETDATE();
            PRINT ''', @DatabaseName, ' updated canary table.''
        END;
        ELSE IF @Count < 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.canary (LastUpdated) VALUES (GETDATE());
            PRINT ''', @DatabaseName, ' inserted into canary table.''
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.canary;
            INSERT INTO dbo.canary (LastUpdated) VALUES (GETDATE());
            PRINT ''', @DatabaseName, ' truncated and inserted into canary table''
        END;
        ');

        EXEC sp_executesql 
        @SQL
        ,N'@DatabaseName SYSNAME'
        ,@DatabaseName = @DatabaseName;
        
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM SQLCursor
        INTO @DatabaseName;
    END;

    CLOSE SQLCursor;
    DEALLOCATE SQLCursor;
```

Comment: If SQL Sentry isn't showing any signs of blocking, how do you know for sure these two processes are blocking each other? How long does it take for your Transaction Log backup job to run? Maybe you have a heavily transactional database and every 15 minutes is a lot of data needed to be backed up, causing general server / resource contention?...but this is just a guess in the wind.

Comment: @J.D. resources on the server during the time span are within normal operation, killing the spid for the update has, on numerous occasions, caused the prolonged log backup to finish almost immediately

Comment: How long does the log backup normally take?

Comment: When the blocking happens, you'll want to gather the data and update the question as without any data it's going to be almost impossible to give any help.